# calling a process from python

Tags: python

I am calling a perl script from python. The perl script retrieves a large data set in batches from a webserver which takes time. This perl script is executed in the loop. It does the job fairly well but during the last run of the loop, while the script is still downloading, it executes the rest of the python code.

I want to know what is the best way to call another program in python, and when running the perl script, the python process to wait till the execution of the perl script finishes as the rest of the python code is processing the data downloaded. I have read about threading but not sure how to implement it in my case.

the code is

```
for expr in names_dict[keys]:
    subprocess.call(["./test.pl", expr, absFilePath])
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks,

Comment: `subprocess.call` waits until the subprocess ends. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Jochen Ritzel is right -- is it possible that the perl script is exiting before the data is fully downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess.Popen(). Check out this blog post:

http://trifoliummedium.blogspot.com/2010/12/running-command-line-with-python-and.html